# Jar merging for debug throwing duplicate entry with android?

Tags: java, android, duplicates

Im getting this error when trying to run my build:

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.> com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/AnimatorRes.class
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
        compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:1.9.0@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }
        compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
        compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
        compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.0.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
        compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
        compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.+@aar'
    }
```

Here is a pic of my libs

[image]

Im hoping someone here can help me find out what the issue is. Im using android studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try excluding the `support-v4`** since the `google-play-services` already contains the `support-v4`

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0')
{
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

if it doesn't work,
**Clean the project and rebuild it.**

Else, try setting `multiDexEnabled` in the gradle file

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```