# In Android Studio grade, duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/ads/AdActivity.class

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I am developing Android app with Android Studio.

I am using google-play-services, however when I run my App in my Android device I encounter the following error.

***build.gradle***

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.myApp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'com/google/android/gms/ads/AdActivity'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.1'
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar')

    android {
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
}
```

***error***

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':myApp:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/ads/AdActivity.class

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':myApp:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/ads/AdActivity.class
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:54)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:57)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:173)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:244)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:231)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/ads/AdActivity.class
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.JarMergingTransform.transform(JarMergingTransform.java:117)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$3.call(TransformTask.java:178)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$3.call(TransformTask.java:174)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/ads/AdActivity.class
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.JarMerger.addJar(JarMerger.java:161)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.JarMerger.addJar(JarMerger.java:121)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.JarMergingTransform.transform(JarMergingTransform.java:107)
    ... 26 more
    enter code here
```

I have no idea why com/google/android/gms/ads/AdActivity.class is duplicated.

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Usually this kind of issue is solved by performing `./gradlew clean` in the project or invalidating caches and restart the Android Studio. If this doesn't work, then you can try to manually delete the duplicated class. Also, make sure the play service libraries that you use in your project have the same version, because sometimes it causes these error. For more information, you can check this related SO question [33487780](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33487780/jar-merging-for-debug-throwing-duplicate-entry-with-android).

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because there are more than one AdActivity.class in your project.

you can ignore one of them in your build.gradle file.

add this to your build.gradle:

```
packagingOptions{
    exclude 'com/google/android/gms/ads/AdActivity.class'
}
```

then build -> clean, rebuild the project.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I add above code, however it does not work well. The same error still occurs.

Comment: where you add above code ?  you should add it as a child of android {},
just like:
android {
   ...
   packagingOptions{...}


}

Comment: I added the above code in my question. I think I properly added. Is it correct?